# Formating a text file in python 2

Tags: python, text

I have a file text that has the following rows:

```
1231231.txt
231231.txt
24141241.txt
3123123.txt
341241241.txt
4123412.txt
iplist.txt
```

What i want to know is how can i make the lines look like this:

```
1231231
231231
24141241
3123123
341241241
4123412
```

in python 2. 
I have tried something like this with no succes :

```
with open('iplist.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        line.rstrip('.txt')
        for ch in line:
            if ch == '.txt':
                ch = ''
f.close
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with open('iplist.txt') as fd:
    my_list = [line.strip().rstrip('.txt') for line in fd]

print ' '.join(my_list)
```

outputs:

```
1231231 231231 24141241 3123123 341241241 4123412
```

assuming this:

```
$ cat iplist.txt 
1231231.txt
231231.txt
24141241.txt
3123123.txt
341241241.txt
4123412.txt
```

Please note that you do not need to close the filehandle when using the `with` construct. As soon as it moves out of scope the filehandle will be automatically closed.